# Return data between two dates from a MDX Query SSAS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssas, mdx, cube

I'm trying to filter data between two date ranges. Its data type is `datetime`.
I have generated the query via the Query designer in SSAS.

**Below is sample of the dataset I have:**

[image]

**Sample image of Measure groups and dimensions:**

[image]

**Sample Filter I have used:**

[image]

**Generated MDX Query:**

```
`SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Status] } ON COLUMNS, NON EMPTY { ([Lobby].[Added Local Time].[Added Local Time].ALLMEMBERS ) } DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_VALUE, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS FROM ( SELECT ( [Lobby].[Added Local Time].&[2020-01-02T10:32:37.806667] : [Lobby].[Added Local Time].&[2020-02-19T13:43:13.833333] ) ON COLUMNS FROM ( SELECT ( { [Lobby].[Status].[All] } ) ON COLUMNS FROM [LTS KROI DEMO])) WHERE ( [Lobby].[Status].[All] ) CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FORMATTED_VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, FONT_NAME, FONT_SIZE, FONT_FLAGS`
```

**Problem:**

Issue is that it doesn't filter the data according to the given `datetime` ranges. Neither gives any error.

If I use the only the Filter - Status a specific value without giving all it all works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was able get the desired result by following the answer of
>   @GregGalloway by making a small change to the parameter I passed as
>   the date. When I removed time passing the date to the `Cdate` function
>   it work fine.

```
SELECT { [Measures].[Status] } ON COLUMNS, NON EMPTY { 
Filter(
 [Lobby].[Added Local Time].[Added Local Time].ALLMEMBERS,
 [Lobby].[Added Local Time].CurrentMember.MemberValue >=  CDate("2020-01-02") 
 and [Lobby].[Added Local Time].CurrentMember.MemberValue <= CDate("2020-02-19")
) 
} DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_VALUE, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS 
FROM [LTS KROI DEMO]
CELL PROPERTIES VALUE
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try the Filter function. It will be slower but should work since the approach you took only works if the exact date time exists

```
SELECT { [Measures].[Status] } ON COLUMNS, NON EMPTY { 
Filter(
 [Lobby].[Added Local Time].[Added Local Time].ALLMEMBERS,
 [Lobby].[Added Local Time].CurrentMember.MemberValue >=  CDate("2020-01-02 10:32:37.806667") 
 and [Lobby].[Added Local Time].CurrentMember.MemberValue <= CDate("2020-02-19 13:43:13.833333")
) 
} DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_VALUE, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS 
FROM [LTS KROI DEMO]
CELL PROPERTIES VALUE
```

Comment: This gives the following error :
Query preparation failed.Type mismatch.  (Microsoft SQL Server 2016 Analysis Services) AND I tried adding the T in between the date times too didnt seems to work